# Importing Java Class from a Python (Jython) Script fails

Tags: python, java, windows, batch-file, jython

I need to automate execution of a small programm written in Java.
The programm has an API that can be accessed through a Python script that I am calling from Jython-Standalone. My Python script needs to import two java classes (modules) but only one is recognized.
Furtheremore, I am trying to automate execution of the script through a batch file.

The Python script resides outside the *.jar file in which the java classes are located, thus I am inserting the *.jar path with sys.path.insert.
So far the code looks like this:

```python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Program Files/HEC/HEC-HMS/4.10/lib/vortex-0.10.30.jar')
from mil.army.usace.hec.vortex.io import BatchImporter
print('Imported BatchImporter')
from mil.army.usace.hec.vortex.geo import WktFactory
```

This results in:

> `Imported BatchImporter`

> `ImportError: No module named geo`

What is weird is that the first import works properly but not the second one.

`mil.army.usace.hec.vortex.io` and `mil.army.usace.hec.vortex.geo` is the directory structure containing the Java classes and I have checked and double checked and the classes are in did under this structure.

I thought maybe there is some weird character on "mil.army.usace.hec.vortex.geo" so I have tried all sorts of capital and small letters combinations to no avail.

I am not a programmer and have never had any experience with Java or Jython, so plase bare with me if I am not expressing the whole issue properly.

In case it is useful, here is the BAT file content I am using to call the met_data_import.py script.

```batch-file
SET "HMS_HOME=C:\Program Files\HEC\HEC-HMS\4.10"
SET "PATH=%HMS_HOME%\bin;%HMS_HOME%\bin\gdal;%PATH%"
SET "PROJ_LIB=%HMS_HOME%\bin\gdal\projlib"
SET "GDAL_DATA=%HMS_HOME%\bin\gdal\gdal-data"
SET "CLASSPATH=%HMS_HOME%\lib\*"
"%HMS_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\Users\..\..\jython-standalone-2.7.3.jar C:\Users\..\..\..\GRID_Importer\met_data_import.py
```

Some things to consider:

- I would like to keep using jython-standalone if possible.
- I cannot modify anything within the *.jar file.

Thanks for any help. I will be happy to improve the question if needed.

Following @Charles Duffy advice I searched inside the jar file through the CMD (by the way I am in a Windows environment): `tar -tf vortex-0.10.30.jar | findstr geo` and for comparisson `...| findstr io` and here is what it spitted out:

> `mil/army/usace/hec/vortex/geo/`...

> `mil/army/usace/hec/vortex/geo/WktFactory.class`...

and

> `mil/army/usace/hec/vortex/io/`...

> `mil/army/usace/hec/vortex/io/BatchImporter.class`...

Comment: What's the specific exception you get from importing the second class? (Is it a vanilla ImportError, or anything more specialized?)

Comment: Does using `unzip -l vortex-3.10.30.jar | grep -E 'BatchImporter|WktFactory'` show anything obvious that's different between the two?

Comment: For that matter, what results does `unzip -l vortex-3.10.30.jar | grep geo` emit? I wouldn't be astonished if there were a separate jar for geographic extensions or such, but without seeing the library that's just speculation.

Comment: It is as you call it a vanilla ImportError. I will check what happens after running unzip and will add to the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: (err, 0.10.30, ignore my repeated typo above; reading the codebase to 0.10.30, it looks like it _did_ contain the WktFactory class at that time)

Comment: Please see my modified question